# Problem printing wirelessly on a new Brother printer MFC-J1010DW

Tags: 18.04, printing, brother

I'm having difficulty printing wirelessly on an all-in-one Brother MFC-J1010DW printer. Before downloading any drivers, I created a static IP address in my router's administrative console--just for the wireless printer. I was, then, able to successfully connect the printer to my Wi-Fi network using the static IP address that I created.

I, then, proceeded to go on the support [page](https://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadtop.aspx?source_c=cinst&c=us&lang=en&prod=mfcj1010dw_us_eu_as) for the MFC-J1010DW printer and made sure to click on "Linux" and, then, "deb". After that, I was redirected to a new page where I was given the opportunity to download a bunch of drivers. **Not being sure which driver to download**, I downloaded the "Driver Install Tool" under "Utilities". I, then, followed the instructions by typing into a terminal:

```
cd Downloads
gunzip linux-brprinter-installer-2.2.3-1.gz
sudo bash linux-brprinter-installer-2.2.3-1
```

The terminal then asked me to specify the model of the printer, so I entered:

```
MFC-J1010DW
```

It, then, asked me to specify the URI of the printer, so I typed:

```
I
```

to specify that I wanted to enter an IP address.

Lastly, I proceeded to enter the printer's static IP address without the "https://" part.

The terminal then downloaded a bunch of packages, yet, for some reason, I still can't print anything wirelessly.

What am I doing wrong? I'm on Ubuntu 18.04.

Edit1: I should add that I do see a printer labeled MFC-J1010DW under Settings>Devices>Printers, but when I want to print something, nothing comes out of the printer, and it only says that the print job is processing.

Edit2: Added a link to the Brother support page.

Comment: Browse to the CUPS GUI at `http://localhost:631`, click on the "Admin" tab, and add your printer there.

Comment: @waltinator OK, I entered my username and password, but I'm not sure which option to click on now. Which of these options should I select?                                                                                                        Local Printers:CUPS-BRF (Virtual Braille BRF Printer)
HP Printer (HPLIP)
HP Fax (HPLIP)
Discovered Network Printers:  
Other Network Printers:  LPD/LPR Host or Printer
Backend Error Handler
Internet Printing Protocol (https)
Internet Printing Protocol (http)
Internet Printing Protocol (ipp)
Internet Printing Protocol (ipps)
AppSocket/HP JetDirect

Comment: @waltinator The list of Discovered Network Printers comes up empty.

Comment: @waltinator Please help. I have important documentation that I need to print out today, and I can't send off the documentation until I get the printer to work.

Comment: Put a `.pdf` of your document onto a USB key (exFat) and take to a Staples or local internet cafe, if its urgent.

Comment: Can you `ping` the printer's IP address?

Comment: @waltinator I was able to get printing functionality by directly connecting the printer to my machine using a USB cable. However, I did buy a wireless printer, so I would still like to be able to print documents wirelessly. I pinged the printer when it wasn't directly connected to my computer and got a "destination host unreachable" message back.

Comment: Give the output of `driverless`

Comment: @brian_p `driverless` comes up empty.

Comment: @Brian Daniels There isn't any connection to the printer. Yor pinging also tells you that. You have a network issue, not a printing problem.